# Linux Shell Script Stuck

Tags: linux, shell

I have a University coursework to complete and I am kind of stuck on this part:

del   - This script should move the file called    to the  dustbin directory in a manner that will allow the file to be restored to its original location later if necessary.

I have made an attempt as shown bellow but It's not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Do you want to delete this file?"
echo "Y/N"
read ans
case "$ans" in
  Y) echo "`readlink -f $1`" >>/TAM/store & mv $1 /~/dustbin ;;
  N) echo "File not deleted" ;;
esac
```

When I run it I get this:

```
./Del: line 8: /TAM/store: No such file or directory
MV: missign destination file operand after '/~/dustbin'
```

Also How can use User input to enter the name of the file? or can you not do that.

P.S. `~` is the root directory, `TAM` is my Directory, `store` is the file and `dustbin` is the `dustbin` directory in the `root`. `Del` is the name of the script

Comment: You haven't told us what isn't working.

Comment: I'd say it's very possible to make a "better" solution, but one thing you probably meant is `&&` not `&`. Regarding your second question, if it's possible to let the user input a file name; a hint: How are you reading the users answer? Perhaps that could be used to read a filename? ;) Thirdly `$1` contains the first (if any) argument to the program.

Comment: Make sure that `$1` is not empty. It seems like it is empty.

Comment: Thanks to Jite for the the & problem, got rid of one error, I will take what else you said and try to make some edits.

Comment: btw, you need to call the script as `./Del file` (if you haven't already) or else `$1` would be empty

Comment: Note that `~` isn't the `root` directory it's your home directory, the shell expands `~` to `/home/TAM/` the `root` directory is `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said it's course work I won't give you a complete solution, but a pretty simple(simplified) start:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    printf "You didn't give an argument, please input file name: \n"
    filename=READ_FILE_NAME_HERE
elif [$# -eq 1 ]; then
    filename=$1
else
    printf "Error: You gave to many parameters!\n"
    exit 1
fi

# Does the file exist (and is a regular file)?
[ -f "$filename" ] || {
    printf "Error: File doesn't exist or isn't a regular file.\n"
    exit 2
    }

Do_you_really_want_to_delete_the_file?
Do_the_remove_magic
```

That should get you started on the "either take parameter input, or if none, allow user to input filename"-problem.

If you get past the checks, you know that filename contains a valid file name, so you could remove the `readlink` call, (although it won't give you the full path then), but you could use `printf "$filename" >>DEST` etc.

There is a lot of good information to read in the manual for `bash`. (Try: `man bash`)

Comment: Thanks man, I shall work on getting that to work and reading the manual.

Comment: I changed my answer regarding `readlink`, although I've never had to use it it seems like I was testing it in a wrong way. I've edited my answer about that part. Just note that `$#` is number of arguments to the program, as in `./del arg1 arg2 arg3` would set `$# equal to 3`, and `$1 equals arg1` etc.